# Query to Append a Number to a Record it it finds a duplicate

Tags: sql, append

I have an sql table with the following fields: Letter, Number, Result

```
Title   Name    Result  
Mr      Mark    
Mr      Mark    
Mr      Luke    
Mr      John
Mr      John
```

I need to create an update query to have the result as

```
Title   Name    Result
Mr      Mark    MrMark
Mr      Mark    MrMark2
Mr      Luke    MrLuke
Mr      John    MrJohn
Mr      John    MrJohn2
```

Note that the second and the fifth record had a number 2 appended since it already found the same record (same Title and Name) previously.

Please help.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: There are a number of questions about finding duplicates on here, so please see about using one of the existing answers as a base.  What distinguishes one row from another?  SQL doesn't really have a concept of _stored_ rows, you have to specify an order on retrieval.  When dealing with duplicates (removal or update or whatever), you need some way to make rows unique, or the row you update may not be the one you expect/both rows may have the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is MS SQL, try using ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY?

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Title NVARCHAR(200), Name NVARCHAR(200), Result NVARCHAR(200));

INSERT @temp
    SELECT 'Mr', 'Mark', NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mr', 'Mark', NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mr', 'Luke', NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mr', 'John', NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mr', 'John', NULL

SELECT * FROM @temp

DECLARE @tempWithOrdering TABLE (RowNum INT, Title NVARCHAR(200), Name NVARCHAR(200), Result NVARCHAR(200));

INSERT @tempWithOrdering
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Title ), Title, Name, Result FROM @temp 

SELECT * FROM @tempWithOrdering 

SELECT 
    Title,
    Name,
    Result = (
        SELECT TOP(1) Name + 
            CASE RowNum
                WHEN t1.RowNum THEN ''
                ELSE CAST(t1.RowNum AS NVARCHAR(12))
            END
        FROM @tempWithOrdering 
        WHERE Name = t1.Name
    )
FROM @tempWithOrdering t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using sql server and the duplicate is on the field 'Name' .Try this.
Use Analytic fn ROW_NUMBER() ;

If it is Oracle use **||** instead of **+**

```
WITH TEMP AS
(
SELECT Title ,  Name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY bill_period) AS RK
FROM TABLE1
)
SELECT Title ,  Name,Title + Name +RK FROM TEMP;
```